# "Prettier - Code formatter" is not working in Visual Studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code, prettier

I have Visual Code Studio(1.41.1) Editor and I need Auto Formatter

I have installed this code format: [Prettier - Code formatter](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode&ssr=false#overview) Successfully installed but not working,

I also tried to use the command `ext install esbenp.prettier-vscode`
 that too was successful installation but is not working.

I checked that the *composer* is installed properly and the *environment variable path* is given correctly in my system, Also, I added it to the `settings.json` file by looking in the [document](https://github.com/Dickurt/vscode-php-formatter/wiki/Setup): `"phpformatter.composer": true` but not success in auto-formatting my code

Visual Studio Code and System Restart also tried but did not succeed

**Why can't I Auto Formatter in my Visual Studio code use this "Prettier - Code Formatter"?** No errors are received, but the auto formatter is not working

Comment: which os are you using

Comment: or you can press Ctrl+shift+p  and type format document then select prettier format

Comment: `"editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"`

Comment: @harkeshkumar windows 10, yes I tried **Ctrl+shift+p** but not a success

Comment: @UdhavSarvaiya can you try to right click and click format document with then choice

Comment: @vsh It was not set before as suggested by you but now I set the default formatter still did not succeed

Comment: Yes @harkeshkumar  I have already tried but my code is not auto-formatting

Comment: then might be some issue with vscode reinstall it

Comment: @harkeshkumar If success is not achieved at the end, it will have to reinstall vscode

Answer (score 33):

try this, it worked for me

`File -> Preferences -> Settings` (for Windows)

`Code -> Preferences -> Settings` (for Mac)

Search for "`Default Formatter`". In the dropdown, prettier will show as `esbenp.prettier-vscode`.

Answer (score 16):

Maybe the prettier extension is not working for Javascript file.
Open your settings.json for VS Code and paste:

```json
{
  "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
  "[javascript]": { "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode" }
}
```

This might work for you

Comment: I have these settings. It worked yesterday but not today. Why is auto format so hard to make sticky in VSCode?

Comment: Looks like it has to have the language explicitly set like this answer to override the user settings in a workspace. 

Answer (score 6):

You may have local .vscode directory in the root of your project with settings that prevent formatting. Try to edit or remove .vscode local configurations if you have. After close and reopen VS Code.

Comment: This was my problem. A repo I added had it's own prettier setup. I need to run "npm install" so that it added the correct local prettier setup.

Comment: After spending a week in almost my 2 different Mac I came along this and this resolved the issue.just deleted that and every setting is now applied from global settings.json file

Answer (score 2):

as @harkesh kumar said :  press **Ctrl+shift+p** and type **format document** then select **prettier format**, it may work for you

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have and don't want a prettier config file for some reason, you can uncheck the option "Prettier: Require Config"

In settings.json it's `"prettier.requireConfig": true`

In the UI it looks like this: [image: Screenshot of the option in the settings]

Answer (score 2):

For me it was failing silently because I was using `await` inside of a function that wasn't marked with `async`. That raises another question - why would it fail silently here. Regardless, once I fixed that error then prettier began working again.

Comment: Same issue for me... lesson try it on a known good file when you are installing the plugin

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have a file in the root folder with this name **.prettierrc.js**

inside you should have something like:

```
module.exports = {
  bracketSpacing: false,
  jsxBracketSameLine: true,
  singleQuote: true,
  trailingComma: 'all',
  arrowParens: 'avoid',
};
```

Answer (score 1):

disable Prettier -> reload your VSCode -> enable Prettier again. Sometime it cache and not apply your setting.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the issue. I was trying to format code on a remote server.

In the extension page for Prettier, it says:

> This extension is disabled in this workspace because it is defined to run in the Remote Extension Host

Then I clicked on the button "install on remote host ..." and it worked

Answer (score 0):

My answer is for vs code formatting in C#:  and I had this same issue, thanks to @selharem's answer above, I followed the same steps, but encountered " Prettier is the default formatter, but I could not format c# code", upon pressing configure, I had three c# formatter option to select from, one of them was "Csharpier" the c# code formatted in vs code.
There is this, and the second option was the command "dotnet Format", which is included in the official .Net SDK since .Net6

Answer (score -1):

If you wish you can add this formatter instead of prettier for javascript. Open settings.json and enter this for js formatter: "vscode.typescript-language-features"

[steps here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AnLOw.png)

Comment: I don't think that's what OP wants.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe try deleting the whole node_modules folder and running npm install again (when using node)